# JQuery AJAX response value to a label

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, response

Could you please check and let me know what is the problem in the below code. I have the valid value in the response.d (I checked my adding alert), but when I assign that value to label it is not changing the value in label(lblData).

```
function LoadPlanBoard() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myplanboard.aspx/WebLoadPlanBoard",
        data: "{flag:'" + 0 + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#<%=lblData.ClientID %>').val(response.d);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var errMessage = "An error occured serving your request. Please try again.";
            if (jqXHR)
                errMessage = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).Message;
            alert(errMessage);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure.  I would check the value of lblData.ClientID and see what that actually outputs.  It's possible that it's not actually an html element that jquery knows how to assign a value to.

Comment: What does <%=lblData.ClientID %> eval to on the webpage? I'd use a breakpoint on that line and double-check that it's what you think it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels in ASP.NET are rendered as span tags I think.  I'd try using `.html(htmlString)`.

Comment: this has nothing to do with ASP.NET.  .val() should only be used with form elements.

Comment: So the type of element that is actually sent to the browser is off-topic for this question?

Answer (score 2):

.val() is for reading values of form controls.  You should use .text(): http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: I believe that val() returns the value and val(value) sets the value.

Comment: I respect your believes, but the doc page I linked to seems to say otherwise ;)

Comment: "Description: Set the value of each element in the set of matched elements."

Comment: .val is not read only, for textbox I am able to use the .val, for label only it is not working.